# Where does the proof of unique factorization fail for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

I know that unique factorization does not hold for all rings, such has the much-used example $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. It seems that Euclid's lemma does not hold for these rings, and so on. However, there are proofs of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic which do not use Euclid's lemma, and moreover do not seem to use any particular properties of the positive integers (see for instance [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Elementary_proof_of_uniqueness) or (better) the alternate proof given [here](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/MA111_Wikipedia_Fundamental-Theorem-of-Arithmetic_6.8.2012.pdf)). Why does this proof fail for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers the alternate proof in your second link:  It starts off using the well ordering principle of the natural numbers.   But we don't have that basic well ordering of our usual $<$ on $\mathbb Z [\sqrt {-5}]$ that cooperates nicely with our other operations.

Comment: So any well-ordered ring is a UFD?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you accept the axiom of choice, ANY set can be well ordered.  You need a well ordering that also preserves the operations

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively the cell of the lattice built with $1$ and $\sqrt{-5}$ is too large.
The counterexample is $6=2\cdot 3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$

Comment: I'm aware of the counterexample, but what I don't see is why the proof doesn't apply. What do you mean by the lattice?